# Ubuntu does not login

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, login

I have installed (via terminal) these packages (because my `Gvim` had a warning about `libgail`):

```
libgail-3-0
libevince3-3
libwebkitgtk-3.0-0
nautilus
```

(I wanted to re-install the first package, when removing it Ubuntu forced to remove the other 3, then I installed all them again)

After reboot, I can't login *(after entering the password the screen refreshes again I enter the password and it hangs)*

Can I solve the problem(s) with live CD without erasing all my data and install everything again?

Comment: What happens if you do Ctrl + Alt + F1 to login?  Will it let you?

Comment: Yes, it lets me to login.

Answer (score 4):

To reset everything to the way it was before you removed the applications, once you  boot to recovery mode by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> enter you username and password, and then reinstall the Ubuntu-desktop meta package.
Code:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Then reboot with
Code:

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Can I reinstall from live CD?(older version)

Comment: No , older CD of ubuntu not good for this , because 12.04 Ubuntu-desktop is differ to Ubutnu 11.10 . so the thing is you need 12.04  Live if you want to get it from a LIVE CD .

Comment: The 12.04 on my computer is newer(updated) than my live CD(12.04). If it's good how can I reinstall with CD? Does this operation remove my data or it's just like a normal update?